# How to reuse a large dynamic query without repeating it?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, reusability

i have ONE parametrized (dynamic) query i want to REUSE in a oracle procedure (or even in a oracle package if possible) like this:

```
cursor q (p1 integer, p2 integer, p3 ...) as
select .... from .... where col1 = p1 and col2 = p2 and ....
```

and later do something like this in subsequent queries

```
select ... 
from t1, t2, ..., q (a, b, c)
where q.c1 = t1.tc1
and q.c2 = t2.tc2
....


select ... 
from n1, n2, ..., q (a, b, c)
where q.c1 = n1.tc1
and q.c2 = n2.tc2
....
```

if the query was static i've used VIEWS but its not..
is there some other simpler ways instead of filling and using lots of additional objects?

Comment: i actually want to reuse the code rather then reuse the results (but if possible reusing the results would be even nicer)

Comment: actually the query is not so dynamic, it doesnt change, only the parameters are

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the "parameterized view" approach described [here on AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1448404423206).

Comment: is this approach works when used in a multi-user envirronment? i mean when the function that wraps all those queries is called by multiple users simultaneously?

Comment: I think not - so perhaps not suitable for your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

To create a type of parameterized view, you can use pipelined functions, as I've detailed in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562665/calling-oracle-stored-procedures-in-r-how-to-get-the-result-set/9176817#9176817).  Use of pipelined functions has its limitations, but Oracle is constantly adding to their capabilities (such as function caches and parallel execution).

See here for a [good article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php) with examples for more.

Be sure to test their performance for your situation of course.  I personally would not go crazy creating a ton of functions in place of simple SQL, but they have their place.

Comment: yes it looks like the best idea so far, but its cumbersome to use, declaring additional structures, taking care of exceptions, ...., i actually need something simpler, at the semantic level, just for better reuse of the code

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something, but why not just create the view as:

```
create view q as
select .... from ....
```

i.e. without the 3 parameters in the WHERE clause (`where col1 = p1 and col2 = p2 and col3 = p3`)

Then apply the 3 "parameters" when you use the view:

```
select ... 
from t1, t2, ..., q
where q.c1 = t1.tc1
and q.c2 = t2.tc2
and col1 = p1 and col2 = p2 and col3 = p3
....


select ... 
from n1, n2, ..., q
where q.c1 = n1.tc1
and q.c2 = n2.tc2
and col1 = p1 and col2 = p2 and col3 = p3
....
```

Comment: yes i could do that but i actually do not accomplish much because most of the code of the first query would be copied to all of the queries...a lot of paste...the goal is to reuse code as much as possible and include it in the first query...also i must mention that p* are variables that i can inject at runtime..non related to subsequent queries

Comment: I don't understand why most of the code would need to be copied - why not just the filters `and col1 = p1 and col2 = p2 and col3 = p3`?

Comment: that view doesn't use parameters/filters so these filters/parameters should be introduced in the subsequent use of the view; so in all the uses of the view one should also add those filters that refers these parameters (a, b, c) and also add join conditions, so in the end can reuse only the 'static' filtering of the view...

Answer (score 1):

You could define the parameterised cursor in a package, then reference it from wherever you need.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/09_packs.htm#i7454

Comment: this is an idea of reusing, but it lacks performance because then u have to manually go over cursor, line by line, instead of somehow joining the cursor to another sql, so that the machine could do the join optimally